# How do I access the "Editor" type defined by TinyMCE in React and TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to figure out how to access types defined in an NPM module.

TinyMCE has an editor React component called `Editor` and it contains an `onInit` method that takes two parameters, an event and the editor itself, also an `Editor` type but different from the component.

So I import the `Editor` component from the library by doing

```
import { Editor as TinyMCEEditor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';
```

And I define the editor as the following...

```
<TinyMCEEditor
   apiKey="asdf"
   onInit={(evt, editor) => onInitCallBack(evt, editor)}
   ...
/>
```

Then I tried to define the callback to match the expected type

```
const onInitCallBack = (_, editor: Editor) => {
   ...
};
```

The strange thing is it is able to recognize the `Editor` type when it is moused over is given as.

```
(parameter) editor: Editor
```

As well as the event's type:

```
(parameter) evt: {
    readonly type: string;
    readonly target: any;
    readonly isDefaultPrevented: () => boolean;
    readonly preventDefault: () => void;
    ...etc
}
```

But on the `onInitCallBack` when I try to define the `Editor` type, it says it cannot find the name 'Editor':

```text
type Editor = /*unresolved*/ any
Cannot find name 'Editor'. ts(2304)
```

What do I need to do to make it see the `Editor` type that is defined in the NPM package?

If I try to use `TinyMCEEditor` as a type I get the following error.

```text
(parameter) editor: Editor
Argument of type ‘import("e:/Git/web-app-release-notes-editor/node_modules/tinymce/tinymce").Editor’ is not assignable to
parameter of type ‘import("e:/Git/web-app-release-notes-editor/node_modules/@tinymce/tinymce-
react/1lib/cjs/main/ts/components/Editor").Editor’

Type ‘Editor’ is missing the following properties from type ‘Editor’: elementRef, boundHandlers, rollbackTimer, valueCursor, and
23 more. t5(2345)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `TinyMCEEditor` as a type?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I have, I'll edit the post to put a screenshot of what happens.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are confusing the React component Editor and the tinymce Editor - notice they have the same name. Surly you need something like...

```
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';
import { Editor as TinyMCEEditor } from 'tinymce';
```

Then

```
const editorRef = useRef<TinyMCEEditor | null>(null);
```

and...

```
<Editor
   onInit={(evt, editor) => editorRef.current = editor}
   ...
/>
```

Although I might have screwed the syntax up here...